# Spring JPA how to retrieve data from arbitrary data structure

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I've got DB data structure, which may contains arbitrary number of columns (user defined), so I want to implement REST controller to obtain such data.
I can retrieve data structure (number and names of columns) only in runtime, so I can't define @Entity before compile.
How do I may implement data retrieve for such kind of data to return it via REST.
Any guesses? Thanks.

Comment: If you have a completely dynamic data model, for which you don't know the columns and / or tables at compile time, then JPA is not really a suitable API to choose. JPA is entirely based on `@Entity` classes, where classes map to tables and fields map to columns, and where you define the mapping at the moment you write the program.

Comment: Although after retrieving the data you can just send it as an arbitrary json by returning a `Map<String, String>` from the rest endpoint method in your `RestController`

Comment: @muasif80 yes, this is just the way I was going to use, but I need a way to retrieve data to map it into response

Comment: @Jesper I was thinking, maybe, about a way to obtain a raw cursor somehow and then map it into response, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Jesper  Or another way may be a dynamically creation of suitable `@Entity` class while processing request?

Comment: No, dynamically creating entity classes would quickly become very complicated. You'd have to generate and compile them at runtime... Use JDBC (Spring's `JdbcTemplate`) instead of JPA, or another API which is suited for such a dynamic data model. Muasif's idea is good: put the result of the query in a `Map`, your Spring controller can then convert that to a JSON response.